# Can I convert from socket2::Socket to Tokio::net::TcpStream?

Tags: sockets, asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio, tcplistener

I would like to use tokio::net::TcpStream as an asynchronous TCP listener. On the other hand, I also want to use set_reuse_address, set_reuse_port, and set_nonblocking in socket2::Socket.

How can I convert from socket2::Socket to tokio::net::TcpStream?

I would like to use tokio::net:TcpStream to listen for efficient and non-blocking TCP connections using asynchronous callbacks.

If you find that such a thing is not possible in the first place or that my understanding of asynchronous is incorrect, I would be grateful if you could point out anything.
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can convert both from/to [`std::net::TcpStream`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html) so you can go through that as common exchange format.

```rust
use tokio::net::TcpStream;
use socket2::Socket;
fn socket_to_async_stream(s: Socket) -> std::io::Result<TcpStream> {
    std::net::TcpStream::from(s).try_into()
}
fn async_stream_to_socket(t: TcpStream) -> std::io::Result<Socket> {
    t.into_std().map(Into::into)
}
```